# Storing std::vector in postgresql with pqxx and retrieving it from the database.

Tags: c++, libpqxx

I need to store the content of an `std::vector<uint8_t>` in a postgresql database and be able to get it out again. I am using the library [pqxx](http://pqxx.org/development/libpqxx) as the "wrapper" for database connection. 
For storing I do this:

```
      std::string query = "INSERT INTO file_pivot(file_id, p_id, deviation) VALUES($1, $2, $3) RETURNING id";

      pqxx::binarystring deviation((void*)&(data), data.size());

      conn.prepare("file_insert", query);
      pqxx::result res = worker.prepared("file_insert")(1)(pivot_id)(deviation).exec();

      worker.commit();
```

Which does work and store it in the data base, from what I can tell, the issue then getting the damn vector out again.

What I tried to do is this:

```
      pqxx::work sworker(conn);
      std::string squery = "SELECT * FROM file_pivot WHERE file_id = $1";

      conn.prepare("select_file", squery);
      pqxx::result sres = sworker.prepared("select_file")(file_id).exec();

      std::vector<uint8_t> rdata;
      if(sres.size() > 0)
      {
          pqxx::binarystring sblob(res[0][3]);
          std::vector<uint8_t>*rrdata = (std::vector<uint8_t>*) sblob.data();
          rdata = *rrdata;
      }
```

But when I then compare the original vector `data` to `rdata` like this:

```
      assert(std::equal(data.begin(), data.end(), rdata.begin()));
```

I get an segmentation fault, I have tried by using `rrdata->begin()` as well same problem. 
Can someone help with this, it is starting to get on my nerves.

Answer (score 1):

`pqxx::binarystring::data` does not return a pointer to a vector, so you can't just treat it as one like you're doing here:

```
          std::vector<uint8_t>*rrdata = (std::vector<uint8_t>*) sblob.data();
```

Rather, the `data()` function [returns](http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/4.0/html/Reference/a00013.html#ad9042fbae551a4404e175a431139ca8c) a pointer to the raw data. To construct a vector out of this, the simplest way is to use the iterators provided by `pqxx::binarystring`, like so:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> rdata(sblob.begin(), sblob.end());
```

Because the iterators are typedef'd as plain old pointers, the `std::vector` constructor will be able to subtract them to allocate the right size for the vector in one go.

Note that this does make a copy of the data; there is no way to construct a vector from existing memory, because a vector always¹ owns the memory it points to.

---

Instead of using a `std::vector<uint8_t>`, it might be easier to use `std::string` instead. A string in C++ is just a series of `char`s (bytes), not characters, and `pqxx::binarystring` has built-in conversions from and to `std::string`.

---

¹ Nitpicker's corner: unless you use a suitable custom allocator. Not recommended.

Comment: Cannot use string for this unfortunatly :)